# pipe output of cut and echo to same line in file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe, echo

I have a bash script that uses grep and cut to send data into an output file. What I haven't been able to achieve is to echo a counter to the same line, in the file, as the output of cut.

This is what I've tried:

```
{ echo -n "B " & input_file.dat | grep -i "Total net con" | cut -d' ' -f10,12; } >> output_file.dat
```

What I get in `output_file.dat` is something like:

```
B result_from_grep_and_cut_1
result_from_grep_and_cut_2
result_from_grep_and_cut_3
...
```

As you can see `B` is present in the first line only. What I am trying to do is to get `B` at the beginning of each line. How can i do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you doing `echo -n "B " & input_file.dat ` ??

Comment: @batMan I thought it would execute the echo command at each iteration (I used `-n` to avoid the newline after echo) but obviously I was wrong. Thanks to @anubhava, now I am aware of the command `sed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `"B "` at the start of each line use:

```
some_command | sed 's/^/B /'
```

for example:

```
ps | sed 's/^/B /'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single ***awk*** expression:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ IGNORECASE=1 }/Total net con/{ print "B ",$10,$12 }' input_file.dat > output_file.dat
```